# Si può dire: "Gli darò un'ascoltata"?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, prepositions

Innanzi tutto, l'italiano è praticamente la mia seconda lingua, quindi lo parlo direi molto bene. Gli errori che farei in italiano li farei anche nella mia lingua madre, e li farei perché la mia testa non riesce a fare di meglio. Comunque, mi è venuto il dubbio se si può dire:

> Gli darò un'ascoltata.

quando qualcuno per esempio ti suggerisce di ascoltare una canzone. Penso che comunque uno direbbe:

> Gli darò un'occhiata.

anche se appunto quello che potrei fare in verità è ascoltare la canzone...

Cosa ne pensate?

Comment: Secondo me, *nulla osta* acché 'sta frase possa essere usata senza cadere in particolari censure.

Comment: È molto informale, ma io nel parlato lo userei. Probabilmente è tecnicamente scorretto, ma è perfettamente comprensibile e almeno a me non suona male.

Comment: Vista: occhiata; tatto: toccata; olfatto: annusata; gusto: assaggiata; udito: ascoltata. Perché no?

Comment: Non ti suggerirei di usare un'espressione poco corretta. Anche se parli bene l'Italiano come seconda lingua, è il modo più efficace per prendere brutte abitudini.

Comment: Non vedo che cos'abbia che non va. L'italiano è una lingua molto fertile: il suo lessico non è composto solo dalle parole registrate sui dizionari. Ci sono innumerevoli prefissi, suffissi e altri modificatori che permettono di formare parole “nuove”, ma che in realtà sono implicite, presenti in potenza nelle regole dell'italiano: basta pensare a tutte le forme alterate dei nomi e degli aggettivi, ai nomi composti e a tantissimi altri casi come quello di cui parliamo (e come il “petaloso” di cui si è parlato di recente ma che è solo uno degli infiniti esempi possibili).

Comment: @DaG: Interessante questa storia sull'aggettivo "petaloso": io non la conoscevo.

Comment: @Josh61: Perché quando qualcuno ti muove delle obiezioni cancelli le tue risposte (e di fatto anche i commenti altrui)?

Comment: @Josh61: Sono d'accordo con DaG: penso che sia un vero peccato che cancelli le tue risposte. Secondo me, si trattava di una buona risposta facendo soltanto delle piccole modifiche con l'obiettivo di usare un tono più prudente (è più prudente scrivere "non appare nei dizionari" che "non esiste"), più d'accordo con [quello che ha detto l'Accademia della Crusca sulla parola "petaloso"](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/laccademia/notizie-dallaccademia/parola-petaloso-possibilit-entrare-vocabolari).

Comment: A mio avviso l'espressione proposta potrebbe funzionare solo in contesti nei quali sia chiaro che si tratta di un calco sull'espressione originale. Non credo cioè che, al momento, la si possa intendere con un significato 'neutro'. Io, personalmente, non la utilizzerei.

Comment: Voglio aggiungere che, in un contesto acnora più informale e di estrema familiarità con la lingua (diciamo pure che è praticamente uno _slang_), si usa anche dire **adesso gli do un occhio** al posto di _tra poco lo guardo_. Invece, _dare un orecchio_ non esiste proprio. Lo si può usare quasi come nonsense per dire in maniera estremamente spiritosa "ascoltare", ma ben sapendo che non esiste neanche come forma colloquiale.

Answer (score 4):

Vorrei rispondere perché mi è capitato di utilizzare e di sentire già questo termine. Ad esempio, un amico ti sta suggerendo alcuni brani di un artista del quale hai chiesto informazioni,

> Ok, gli do un'ascoltata.

Il termine non è formalmente corretto, non è riportato nel dizionario, ma nel contesto giusto è perfettamente comprensibile e difficilmente sostituibile: infatti è difficile indicare altrimenti l'atto con quella sfumatura di distacco o disinteresse. Dire  - Ok, li ascolto - è diverso, forse è parafrasabile con qualcosa del tipo - Appena ho tempo provo a sentirli un po' -.

Detto questo, la risposta della Crusca alla famelica vicenda di *[Petaloso](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/laccademia/notizie-dallaccademia/parola-petaloso-possibilit-entrare-vocabolari)* credo calzi altrettanto bene alla tua domanda. La parola è un sostantivo derivato, ben formato, coprirebbe una lacuna (come sottolieato da @egreg), quindi direi in lizza per una possibile ufficializzazione.

Un'altra curiosità, cercando ho trovato la parola [*Ascoltamento*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tag/ascoltamento/), avrei giurato che non esistesse.

Comment: Grazie per la buona risposta. Per capire: che cosa intendi di preciso con “formalmente corretto”?

Comment: Intendevo dire che non è ufficialmente riconosciuto come un vocabolo della lingua italiana, i.e., non presente in nessun dizionario ufficiale e quindi non utilizzabile in un contesto formale.

Comment: Non esistono dizionari o riconoscimenti “ufficiali” per le parole; i dizionari sono strumenti fatti da esseri umani, che registrano (sempre con un certo ritardo) l'uso concreto, come credo che spieghi bene proprio quell'intervento della Crusca, e non autorizzazioni per usi formali o meno. E inoltre qui parliamo semplicemente di un termine derivato in modo regolare da altri: i dizionari non riportano a lemma neppure “bimbetto” o “ripercorressero”.

Comment: @DaG - bimbetto è un diminutivo e ripercorressero è un tempo verbale. Se uno proprio vuole usare l'espressione "un'ascoltata" potrebbe semplicemente metterla tra virgolette così, forse, diventa più accettabile per tutti. "Petaloso", tra l'altro,  è un aggettivo orrendo e cacofonico. Ma quelli della Crusca non erano i guardiani integerrimi della lingua italiana un tempo?

Comment: E "l'inzupposo" di Banderas dove lo mettiamo?

Comment: @Josh61: Dalle tue risposte mi accorgo che sono completamente incapace di spiegarmi.

Comment: @DaG - il tuo punto di vista è molto chiaro, io non lo condivido. Se un tuo studente scrivesse in un compito "ho dato un"ascoltata alla quinta sinfonia di Beethoven", tu non obietteresti nulla?

Comment: @Josh61: Come sai, l'Accademia della Crusca è oggi un ente scientifico che fa ricerca e divulgazione. Non sono “guardiani integerrimi della lingua italiana”, bensì ricercatori, lessicografi, insegnanti e così via, che studiano, analizzano, spiegano, discutono. Altrimenti sarebbe come se quelli che lavorano in un osservatorio fossero “guardiani integerrimi” dell'eliocentrismo aristotelico.

Comment: @Josh61. Certo, probabilmente lo sconsiglierei a uno studente (ma dipende anche che cosa sta scrivendo, come e perché), ma è diverso: è un fatto di registro linguistico. Probabilmente nel tema o compito medio sono fuori luogo sia “occaso” che “scoreggia”, perché inadatti al registro medio di molti elaborati scolastici, eppure sono entrambi presenti nei dizionari.

Comment: @DaG - diciamo che è una zona grigia che, a mio avviso, potrebbe essere ovviata semplicemente con l'uso delle virgolette per questi neologismi o per i termini inadatti ad uno specifico registro.

Comment: @Dag grazie per il tuo appunto. I dizionari sono dei paragoni di riferimento, è vero l'evoluzione della lingua è difficilmente controllabile. Talvolta è però divertente giocare con essa per esprimere in maniera colorita e sintetica concetti altrimenti più complessi da definire. Voglio ricordare anche un altro caso molto simpatico, il ["perplimere"](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/significato-origine-perplimere) di Guzzanti.

Comment: @Josh61 sottolinea che bisogna comunque delimitare la zona grigia, la lingua va rispettata, e il virgolettato per sottolineare la natura gergale di un neologismo risolve bene la questione.

Comment: Sui dizionari, e su altre questioni ricorrenti, ho scritto [due righe](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/common-misconceptions-when-discussing-language) sul Meta; se qualcuno ha voglia di lasciare un commento, mi fa piacere.

Comment: @Josh61, donnadulcinea: Il virgolettato è una scelta possibile, ma è a sua volta piuttosto carico. Di fatto, chi scrive sta prendendo le distanze dalla parola che sta mettendo fra virgolette, e non è sempre quello che si vuole ottenere.

Comment: @DaG - personalmente trovo l'uso delle virgolette per nulla carico ma molto utile nel porre l'attenzione su un termine o una espressione come non comune o gergale.

Comment: @Josh61: Penso che stiamo dicendo la stessa cosa: se un termine virgolettato “pone l'attenzione” su qualcosa è più carico (ma se non ti piace questo aggettivo, usa pure un sinonimo) dello stesso termine usato senza virgolette, no?

Comment: @DaG - io "petaloso" e "un'ascoltata" li userei sempre e comunque tra virgolette, giusto per capirci.

Comment: @Josh61: Quindi di fatto non li usi, ma li menzioni, che è una scelta perfettamente legittima (e forse in certi casi lo farei anch'io), ma non l'unica, né necessariamente consigliabile a terzi.

Comment: @DaG - mia nonna e le sue amiche usavano spesso il verbo al singolare con sostantivi al plurale, tipo: "dov'è le forchette? Non c'è abbastanza bicchieri sulla tavola!" Io ho sempre detto loro che il loro modo di parlare non era corretto...sembra che oggi invece avrebbero ragione loro.

Comment: @Josh61: Che stai dicendo? Che c'entra? Forse è materiale per una nuova domanda.